# Perp of a subset and closeness.

Tags: inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space. We know that for a subset $S$ of $V$, $S^{\perp}$ is a subspace of $V$. My question is that whether $S^{\perp}$ closed or not in general. I have seen the proof in finite dimensional case but I was unable to understand that does the same goes through in infinite dimention also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^\perp$ is always closed in the norm topology. It is the intersection
of the sets $K_a=\{x\in V:(x,a)=0\}$ over all $a\in S$, which is closed as
$x\mapsto (x,a)$ is continuous.

Comment: in any dimention the function is continious?

Comment: Yes, in the norm topology coming from the norm associated to the inner product.